Get warning when setting port for emulator
When I run the emulator with the following command
emulator -avd Group_00_InstaAcc-Device_A -port 5554 -writable-system -phone-number 49300434405 -no-snapshot-update-time

I get an error in the image when closing the emulator!

I noticed that when I remove the command "-port 5554" from the command to run the emulator, I no longer see this error on my operating system (Mac) when closing the emulator
I also get this additional error when opening the emulator with the port settings in the terminal:
WARNING | UpdateCheck: Failure: No error
none.xml:3: parser error : AttValue: " or ' expected
<html lang=en>
           ^
none.xml:3: parser error : attributes construct error
<html lang=en>
           ^
none.xml:3: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag html line 3
<html lang=en>
           ^
none.xml:3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<html lang=en>
           ^
WARNING | Emulator client has not yet been configured.. Call configure me first!
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000070
 [0x00011ad8115c]
 [0x00011ad80ff1]
 [0x7fff20872d7d]
 [0x69666e6f63206e65]
 [0x7fff207c43d9]
 [0x00010b181375]
 [0x00010ac0a12f]
 [0x00010aa024f4]
 [0x00010a9fe1eb]
 [0x00010a9e7816]
 [0x0001108a8693]
 [0x7fff2082d8fc]
 [0x7fff20829443]
[end of stack trace]
[4183:94324:20240517,032426.947862:WARNING process_memory_mac.cc:93] mach_vm_read(0x7ffee53b9000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[4183:94324:20240517,032427.116379:WARNING crash_report_exception_handler.cc:235] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
Segmentation fault: 11

I get an error when closing the emulator! This does not happen when I run the emulator without setting the port on it! How can I get rid of this error!?
